# Cannot resolve method 'getText()' on TextView / error: boolean cannot be dereferenced?

Tags: java, android

I'm getting this error when attempting to call 'getText' on a TextView in an if statement.  The strange thing is that when I call the same method on the same view in a Log statement right before the if statement, no error pops up.  I've looked at many other similar questions, and I've tried cleaning and rebuilding my build to no avail. When I try to run it, the error that comes up is error: boolean cannot be dereferenced.  TextView is not a primitive type, so I believe I should be able to call a method on it. I have the method below, please let me know if any other code is required.

```
private void doSearch(Cursor query) {
        // get a Cursor, prepare the ListAdapter
        // and set it
        Cursor c = query;
        startManagingCursor(c);


        String[] from = new String[] {"QUANTITY", "_id"};
        int[] to = new int[] {android.R.id.text1};
        SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, c, from, to);
        mListView.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        Log.e("doSearch method:", "has been called");

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(
                new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                            int position, long id) {
                        // When clicked, log with the TextView text
                        Log.e("doSearch method:", "Answer: " + ((TextView) view).getText()); //no error here

                        if(cMap.containsKey((TextView) view).getText()){ //error here
                            //start new activity
                        } else if (chMap.containsKey((TextView) view).getText()){//error here
                            //start new activity
                        } else if (aMap.containsKey((TextView) view).getText()){//error here
                            //start new activity
                        }


                    }
                });
    }
```

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: containsKey() return a boolean not a textview. Hence the error. You probably want get() instead (warning check for null)

Comment: Don't I want a boolean for use in an if statement?

Comment: A boolean has no getText method..

Comment: Oh I see now, what a silly error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the View as an argument to containsKey:

```
cMap.containsKey((TextView) view).getText()
```

should be

```
cMap.containsKey(((TextView) view).getText())
```

The error you are getting basically says that cMap.containsKey(view).getText() is not a boolean

Comment: NB: containsKey accepts an object, so passing a view to it could be ok

Comment: yes but the data logic is not there. I think she was trying to use the textview text as a key but missed a bracket rather than using the view as a key. it just makes more sense

Comment: yes, I added the comment because you answer starts with "**Because** you are passing the View as an argument to containsKey"